# JS and JQuery delay in event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a quantity feild in wordpress (woocommerce)...

It is working, but, i need to fire an event when i Press + or - beside Quantity,
that will "Update cart".

I did it as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery('div.woocommerce')
.on('click', 'input.plus', //When I click on "input.plus
function funkca (){        // Run function
jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click"); //Click a button named update_cart
}
); 
</script>
```

But the "function" (jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click")) needs to be fired cca. 1000ms after the initial click...

Anyone got any ideas?

Kind regards

Comment: setTimeout? ....

Comment: setTimeout(() => jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click"), 1000);

Comment: why dont you trigger the function, that is called when the button is clicked? simulating a real click in js causes problems due how the event q works... setting a timeout is just a workaround no solution

Comment: what is the reason behind 1000ms delay, I can see that you are trying to work around the core problem (guessing debounce). There could be better solution to solve original problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just put a timeout in, as so:

```
jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('click', 'input.plus', function(){ setTimeout(function (){        
    jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click");
}, 1000)});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use setTimeOut function like

```
function funkca (){        // Run function
     setTimeout(function(){ 
         jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click"); //Click a button named update_cart
     }, 1000);

});
```

i hope it might help.